# Toolkit for Asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Does anyone know asp.net mvc toolkit which has a ready tools for typical web developnet tasks(paging, comments, profiles, messaging, etc....) ?

Comment: What's a page listener? Is it javascript that periodically pinging a server for updates?

Comment: ETC could be a lot of things...  Please define the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

mvccontrib is a great project with lots of useful stuff in and well worth a look.

I'd also have a look at teleriks controls which includes some useful bits

http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-mvc/
Also jquery and jquery ui come in very handy..

The asp.net membership providers can handle a lot of your user/profile stuff but may need extending to get the best out of it.  As far as comments and messaging etc ??  there are a number of open source blogging engines and cms tools available.

http://orchard.codeplex.com/

http://blogengine.codeplex.com/

Would be good starting points

Answer (score 3):

Have you checked out http://mvccontrib.codeplex.com/